# Qt command line arguments error

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm a beginner in Qt and currently working on a project, after I've made some changes in my code I couldn't run it, then fixed it but when opening the project the message

`Unable to send command line arguments to the already running instance. It does not appear to be responding. Do you want to start a new instance of Qt Creator?`

keeps popping up, it hadn't before I made those changes. The project runs ok but I had to move it from a file to my desktop because a bug kept appearing. What could I do now to make sure the message doesn't show up anymore? One more thing, I don't know what command line arguments are and I'm sure I didn't use them (at least deliberately).

Comment: Did you check if the instance is already running or not? Which operating system do you use?

Comment: @SumitJha Windows 10. Do you mean I should kill some process in the task manager?

Comment: I had similar issue long back on linux. I just killed the process and it was fine.

Comment: You may be interrested in reading the following: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Arguments

Comment: @JesperJuhl, in my opinion the info isn't relevant to the error. Although it could help in general, since the OP said, that he/she doesn't know what _cla_ is, the problem in this case is a non-responding process from previous attempts to run the project. I am pretty sure, that tomorrow morning (or after any reboot) the problem will be magically gone ;)

Comment: @scopchanov of course it's not relevant to the error. I posted the link purely because OP said he/she didn't know what commandline arguments were.

Comment: stop Qt creator .. make sure no instances of Qt creator are running and restart again.